# Connecting to a WPA2 LAN on Ubuntu with Fluxbox

Tags: ubuntu, fluxbox

I'm trying to connect to a new network with Ubuntu 12.04 and fluxbox, and I'm not sure how to get it working. In the fluxbox menu there aren't any wlan-tools or network-manager, and since I'm not on the network I can't install any additional programs like wlan_radar.

Is there a terminal way to do network scans and connect with a WPA2 password?

Comment: You can do it through the CLI, but it would be much easier for you to use wicd

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu's Network Manager.  You can always disable that using:

```bsh
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Then use:

```bsh
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID
```

To see if you can even see the network.

If so, and you're using wpa2, you'll have to do a few things.  First generate the key/value pair that wpa_supplicant will use to connect:

```bsh
sudo wpa_passphrase "mywireless_ssid" "secretpassphrase" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Next, kill off any dhcp service (just in case it's running)

```bsh
sudo pkill dhcpcd
```

Finally, try to connect:

```bsh
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf &
```

I would maybe not fork it to the background on the first attempt, just to see if it's going to work.

Comment: after 
sudo wpa_passphrase "mywireless_ssid" "secretpassphrase" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

i got the error message: /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf: Permission denied (i did replace the essid and passphrase with the actual one)

Comment: @Lennier: Yes, you [can't redirect output from sudo like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr). Try `wpa_passphrase "mywireless_ssid" "secretpassphrase" | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` instead.

Comment: great, just one last question: i have a password with an exclamation mark (like "lorem_ipsum!") i could pass it with the backslash \ but in the generated file there is the backslash submitted, too. wpa_passphrase "mywireless_ssid" "secretpassphrase\!" | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf Is there any way to submit an exclamation mark without backslash?

Comment: @Lennier - Change the double quotes to single quotes.